# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException with no info in developer console

Tags: android, android-resources, android-assets

I've a **few rare** crash logs like following in my developer console and have no idea what to do with it. About my project I can say following:

- crash log is not pointing to my code anywhere
- I'm not using assets in this project

So I'm stuck at what I could check next... Any ideas?

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
  at android.app.ResourcesManager.createAssetManager (ResourcesManager.java:267)
  at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResourcesImpl (ResourcesManager.java:324)
  at android.app.ResourcesManager.getOrCreateResources (ResourcesManager.java:585)
  at android.app.ResourcesManager.getResources (ResourcesManager.java:659)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources (ActivityThread.java:1918)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources (LoadedApk.java:812)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.<init> (ContextImpl.java:2043)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext (ContextImpl.java:1988)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:5472)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1596)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6316)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:872)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

**Manifest application tag**

```
<application
    android:name="com.my.app.MainApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/derived_app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:name, android:label, android:icon">
```

Comment: In which developer console.?

Comment: What does the `application` element in your manifest look like?

Comment: First thing you should do is upload the mapping.txt file through the console. If you are using proguard for your released apk, go to dev console / android  vital/ Deobfuscation files and upload this file. You can find this file in your release folder i.e. build/ outpus/mapping/release/mapping.txt. It will help you anyways, whenever there are any other errors.

Comment: @SardarKhan google play developer console

Comment: @laalto added this, nothing special in there imho

Comment: @prom85 Another thing that you can do is install release version on your mobile and you will see the error . You can use adb install command

Comment: @codebased this error is rare, nothing that's reproducable... my app works on thousands of devices without any issues...

Comment: @prom85 Have you got mapping file uploaded through the console.

Comment: @codebased do you see any obfuscated code line in the log? So this does not help here not change anything...

Comment: @prom85 Do I see? No! But there is always "what if".  It was a comment not an answer. I also don't see your resource file. I also don't see your manifest. I also don't know if there is a pattern about a specific device.

Comment: I know what is. The stacktrace will be the same. I only commented as well and it was not meant offending, it just does not make sense what you're suggesting. And I tried it, for the sake of proof, and it stays the same. Btw, as written in my post, the complete stack trace does not have any connection to my own code

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project by **Build -> Clean Project** and Do rebuild the project by **Build -> Rebuild Project**.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want replace android:name in manifest merging? I suppose it's wrong. You trying to replace context of application and that leads to app unable to access resources

Try this

```
tools:replace="android:label, android:icon"
```